# Create a hive table from existing avro folder

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

I have a series of avro folders in the folder: `/gobblin` in my hdfs.  I manually created a `avsc` file based on what I know as the source structure of the `avro`.

How do I create a `hive` table from the `avsc` using existing `avro` files already in `hdfs`?

thank you.

UPDATE #1,
I have created a `CREATE TABLE` script to create the hive table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Claims(
     PlanID int,
     ClaimID int,
     ClaimAmount int,
     PhysicianID string,
     ClaimType string,
     CreateDate string,
     ModifyDate string)
ROW FORMAT
SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://hostname.com/gobblin/job-output/Claims/Claims'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='hdfs://hostname.com/gobblin/claims.avsc');
```

The DDL works, but I cannot query.
Inside the `/gobblin/job-output/Claims/Claims` folder rests a series of serialized folders with avro files in each one.  I want them in the table.
How do I work this?

Thanks.

UPDATE #2
Here is my avsc file:

```
{"namespace": "claim.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "claim",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "MemberID", "type": "int"},
     {"name": "PlanID", "type": "int"},
     {"name": "ClaimID", "type": "int"},
     {"name": "ClaimAmount", "type": "int"},
     {"name": "PhysicianID", "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "ClaimType", "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "CreateDate", "type": ["string", "null"]},
     {"name": "ModifyDate", "type": ["string", "null"]}
 ]
}
```

and here is the stack trace:

```
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1449174649821_0008_3_00, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1449174649821_0008_3_00_000001, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Failure while running task:java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found Claims.Claims, expecting Claim.avro.Claim
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:137)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:344)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:179)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable$1.run(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:171)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TezTaskRunner$TaskRunnerCallable.callInternal(TezTaskRunner.java:167)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found Claims.Claims, expecting Claim.avro.Claim
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.run(MapRecordProcessor.java:310)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:148)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found Claims.Claims, expecting Claim.avro.Claim
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerChain.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.io.HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.handleRecordReaderNextException(HiveIOExceptionHandlerUtil.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:355)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveRecordReader.doNext(HiveRecordReader.java:33)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.next(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.split.TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat$TezGroupedSplitsRecordReader.next(TezGroupedSplitsInputFormat.java:141)
        at org.apache.tez.mapreduce.lib.MRReaderMapred.next(MRReaderMapred.java:113)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordSource.pushRecord(MapRecordSource.java:61)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found Claims.Claims, expecting Claim.avro.Claim
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.doAction(ResolvingDecoder.java:231)
        at org.apache.avro.io.parsing.Parser.advance(Parser.java:88)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readFieldOrder(ResolvingDecoder.java:127)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:176)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:151)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:142)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:233)
        at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.next(DataFileStream.java:220)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroGenericRecordReader.next(AvroGenericRecordReader.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroGenericRecordReader.next(AvroGenericRecordReader.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveContextAwareRecordReader.doNext(HiveContextAwareRecordReader.java:350)
        ... 22 more
```

Comment: What do you mean you cannot query? Like nothing shows up? Are you sure there is actually Avro data in the Claims folder and not just empty files?

Comment: inside the Claims folder rests a series of serialized folders:  ie.  20151214222600_full.  when I run the DDL above, then enter `Select count(*) from Claims`  The TEZ engine fails.

Comment: with this error `java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found Claims.Claims, expecting Claim.avro.Claim`

Comment: Can you edit your question to add that error stacktrace as well as your `claims.avsc` schema file?

Comment: Does it matter that you are missing a column in your Hive table for `MemberID`?

Comment: don't know...trying it now.  It was in the avsc file.  one sec.

Comment: Yeah, it will matter. Dunno if the stack trace shows that being the issue. try `desc formatted Claims;` and see if it's at least pulling the schema correctly.

Comment: ok. thanks for being patient.  it came back.  This was the error now: `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.io.IOException: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found Claims.Claims, expecting Claims.Claims`  great.  how do I solve this?